# Objects are not assigning the values in unit test cases

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a method GetConfig() where I am taking values from appsettings.json and assigning to globally declared variables.
I want them to be used in unittest cases so that they will get accessible at throughout class methods wherever needed.
I initialized them in setup method. But they are not getting assigned the values at run time the objects become null.

I have these variables UserInputRequest,appSettings declared globally

```
public UserRequest UserInputRequest=new();

public static Dictionary<string,string> appSettings {get; private set;}
```

```
public void GetConfig()
{
 var Request = new ConfigurationBuilder()            
    .AddJsonFile("usersettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            
 UserInputRequest = Request.GetSection("AppIdentitySettings").Get<List<UserRequest>>().First(); 
            
 var settings = new ConfigurationBuilder()            
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

 appSettings= settings.GetSection("somesettingssection").GetChildren().ToDictionary(x=>x.key,x=>x.value);
}
```

I have used these variables throughout the application so that i can use these settings wherever needed.

In unit test classes

I have initialized these in the setup method but in actual usage the objects are null.
Need an help on this how to initialize them and use them in unit test cases.

Note : As I am beginner to write unit test cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "declared globally"? In which class? Can you show the Setup method of your usit test and how you use the class in the tests?

Comment: The issue got sorted : I missed to assign the actual assigned variable to my mocked object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case we need to assign the declared varaible to mocked object so that your mocked object will have that globally declared object assigned.

```
mockeobject.object=<your globally declared variable>
```